# How can i access this object key in this conditional?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Write a function countWords that, when given a string as an argument, returns an object where keys are the words in the string, and values are the number of occurrences of that word within the string:

```
function countWords(string){
    string = string.split(" ");
    var newObj = {};
    for(var i = 0 ; i === newObj.string ; i++){
        if(newObj['i'] === newObj[string]){
           newObj[string[i]] = i ;
        }
    }
        return newObj;
    }
countWords("hello hello"); // => {"hello": 2}
countWords("Hello hello"); // => {"Hello": 1, "hello": 1}
countWords("The quick brown"); // => {"The": 1, "quick": 1, "brown": 1}
```

I realized since you do not need to count the index of the split string, you have to change the conditions from `i < string.length` to `i === key value of of the objects`. Why can't I access the strings with `newObj.string`?

Comment: `newObj.string` doesn't make sense on a newly defined empty object that has no properties yet. You want to use the array length so not sure where the idea you need to change it comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `reduce()` instead of `for` loop.

```js
function countWords(string) {
  return string.split(' ').reduce(function(r, e) {
    r[e] = (r[e] || 0) + 1;
    return r;
  }, {})
}
console.log(countWords("hello hello"))
console.log(countWords("Hello hello"))
console.log(countWords("The quick brown"))
```

With `for` loop your code could go like this.

```js
function countWords(string) {
  var string = string.split(" ");
  var newObj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    newObj[string[i]] = (newObj[string[i]] || 0) + 1
  }
  return newObj;
}
console.log(countWords("hello hello"));
console.log(countWords("Hello hello"));
console.log(countWords("The quick brown"));
```

Comment: yes i saw this answer before, thank you. But i want to know how to solve it with the for loop before i move into reduce

Comment: thank you so much!! i guess i was kind of close and did not need to change the string.length. but one more question..


 newObj[string[i]] = (newObj[string[i]] || 0) + 1

is this what you call a ternary operator? with truthy and falsy values?

Comment: You're welcome, that is not ternary operator this is `(condition) ? true : false`, that just sets each key default value to 0.

Comment: I still don't understand the `(condition) ? true : false`. I've never seen this anywhere. If you don't mind, can you please clarify this line: `newObj[string[i]] = (newObj[string[i]] || 0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countWords(string){
  return string
    .split(" ")
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (curr in acc) {
        acc[curr]++
      } else {
        acc[curr] = 1
      }
      return acc
    }, {})
}
console.log(countWords("hello hello"));
console.log(countWords("Hello hello"));
console.log(countWords("The quick brown"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way by using the `hasOwnProperty` function to check if a property exists in the JavaScript Object, if it does increment the count and if it doesn't then initialize the count to 1.

```js
function countWords(data) {
  var words = data.split(" ");
  var item = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var prop = words[i];
    item.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? item[prop] ++ : item[prop] = 1;
  }

  console.log(item);
  return item;
}

countWords("hello hello"); // => {"hello": 2}
countWords("Hello hello"); // => {"Hello": 1, "hello": 1}
countWords("The quick brown"); // => {"The": 1, "quick": 1, "brown": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

newObj[string[i]] = (newObj[string[i]] || 0) + 1
according to my understanding this statement is used to check for duplicity
suppose you crated  an empty object and then stored the key value pair in it by using this statement "(newObj[string[i]] || 0) + 1" you are checking if the default value of the key is zero if its zero you then increment its value by 1 if there are multiple value for the same key by doing this you can get the unique value in the array

Example

```
const uniqueValues = arr => {
  let newObj = {}
  for (let val of arr){
    newObj[val] = [newObj || 0] + 1;
  }
  return (Object.keys(newObj).length);
}
uniqueValues([1,1,1,1,1,2]);
```